# Не работает: new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Tags: javascript

Хочу из JavaScript записать данные в файл. Нашёл пример, но у меня он не работает, на операторе:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

В отладчике браузера IE11 вижу надпись:

> "Невозможно создание объекта сервером программирования объектов"

Что это значит? Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: В тему: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928117/how-to-use-filesystemobject-to-read-file-in-javascript

Comment: через wsh запускать надо. гугли wsh javascript

Answer (score 1):

Разреши JS взаимодействовать с ФС, был бы ужас. Любой "хацкер" посчитает своим долгом попытаться "скрытно, в стиле Assassin's Creed" загрузить гадость, пишущую на экране очень обидные слова :)
И это как минимум, ведь авторы серьёзного софта и так эксплуатируют дыры в браузерах, с такой возможностью вообще разгул будет.

Браузеру можно предложить скачать файл через заголовок или атрибут [`download`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).
Плюс - JS не нужно писать в файлы, он для другого создан. И если архитектура требует от него подобных действий, это верных повод задуматься о правильности планирования самой архитектуры.

Comment: JS для другого создан? повезло что создатели mongodb и nodejs про это не знали ;)

Comment: Не понял. Про "download" прочёл, но это не то, что мне надо. А надо мне считать данные из файла (координаты нескольких точек), построить между ними пути с помощью API Яндекс карт, а потом записать времена этих путей в другой файл. И как мне изменить архитектуру?

Comment: @PashaPash, То порты в другие ветки эволюции, канонЪичному JS это не нужно.

Comment: @Александр, Считывать данные только с сервера, посчитать маршрут тоже там можно (точно не знаю, не работал с их API), после просто предложить сохранить файл заголовком. В крайнем случае - отправить на сервер результаты расчёта и пусть сервер опять предложит сохранить файл. Есть FileAPI, но оно позволяет работать с файлами, который пользователь выберет, сохранять всё же нельзя. Ну или же я отстал от жизни :)

Answer (score 0):

Это значит, что эту дыру давно пофиксили.

Используй скачивание файла вместо этого.

Comment: Не совсем понял. "Дыру пофиксили" - это, видимо, запретили операцию "new ActiveXObject"? А как именно использовать скачивание файла вместо этого?

Comment: @Александр, используй `Blob` и `<a download="smth.bin">...</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Scripting.FileSystemObject` отмечен как "небезопасный". Возможность "взять и записать данные в файл" на клиентской стороне - это дырень в безопасности браузера. Поэтому возможность создание отключена по умолчанию. Для включения придется поменять настройки безопасности для текущей зоны:

Tools → Internet Options → Security → Custom Level → ActiveX controls and Plugins →  Initialize and script Activex controls not marked as safe for script → Enabled или Prompt.

Но лучше так не делать - работать будет только в IE, и только при смене настроек безопасности.